# ListView PerformItemClick not working

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

This question has been asked a lot of times and I've systematically gone through each and tried to find which version of `performItemClick` works. Unfortunately I just can't get any of them to work despite my onclick method being called.

I have a listview with 5 items embedded into a fragment. This fragment is controlled by a fragmentstatepageradapter and a viewpager. I'm trying to restore the saved state.

```
        lv.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list,
                R.layout.list_imageview, new String[] { "answer" },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }));
```

The simple adapter takes in a custom layout which has a textview and imageview within a layout. Initially the imageview is null and on click it is set to a tick or cross. This works when clicking the items myself just doesn't work programatically as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                lv.performItemClick(lv.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null),
                        i, i);
                Log.e("restoring state", "" + i);
            }
        }
    }
```

I can confirm that `onViewStateRestored` is called and `onItemClick` is also called. I assume it's a problem in the way I'm performing the item click. I am currently just trying to get it work; I know I haven't yet checked which items have been clicked to selectively click them but that's an easy `boolean[]` away.

I thank you for your help, and sorry for such a simple question that's been repeated quite a few times; despite reading them I am still unable to get them to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume it's a problem in the way I'm performing the item click.

Right now you call `performItemClick` giving it a **new** `View` created by the `getView` method of the adapter. The problem is that if you setting the image is somehow related to the row view the `onItemClick` callback receives, you'll not see any results as that view is not related(it's "in the air") to the row view that is actually seen on the screen(or present in the `ListView`). But I'm just guessing.

Anyway, you shouldn't tie that `ImageView` work to the `OnItemClickListener`, you should implement it at the adapter level(and call `notifydataSetChanged()`), especially as you're trying to set multiple rows at once.

Comment: That explains it amazingly! I'm trying that

Comment: Testing it looks like that it definitely isn't taking the IDs of the original shown list but indeed getting a new view. How do I implement it at the adapter level? (Please and thanks)

Comment: @AndroidPenguin I don't know what you're doing in the `onItemClick` method(and I also didn't see that you use `SimpleAdapter`, aren't the ImageViews repeating when you scroll?>). I would modify the `list` that backs the adapter so each row `Map` includes another column named `state` to hold the state of the `ImageView`. In the `onViewStateRestored` I would then update the `state` column in each map and call `notifyDataSetChanged`. You'll need to make some modifications on how you work with the adapter. See this https://gist.github.com/4641788